# Cómo reemplazar un texto que se repite en una página por otro que yo quiera?

Tags: wordpress

he estado investigando y he probado de todas formas posibles, incluso descargando Poedit y traduciendo , pero no me sale.
La única opción que me queda es reemplazar un texto de wordpress que dice "No hay comentarios" por uno que diga "No hay opiniones".
Simplemente que reemplaze todas las frases iguales sin necesidad de estar dentro de un div ya que no puedo editarlo.

Pondría el script en el header y que cada vez que encuentre la frase, que la reemplaze por la otra.

PD: He llegado a probar esto:

```
<script>
var texto = "No hay comentarios";
var resultado = texto.replace('No hay comentarios', 'No hay opiniones');
</script>
```

Pero entiendo que es muy básico y no funciona, no se mucho de esto.

Sería posible esto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si ese texto aparece en una pagina entonces esta dentro de tu theme en algun lado.. ahi es donde lo tenes que cambiar...

Comment: la ubicación depende del theme ( o si hay un plugin que maneje los comentarios ), por ejemplo en el theme twetynineteen que viene con wordpress lo encontras en [template-parts/post/discussion-meta.php](https://github.com/WordPress/twentynineteen/blob/master/template-parts/post/discussion-meta.php#L18).  la función `__( "texto" )` [trae la traducción si está disponible](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedo plantearte 2 opciones:

La opcion mas natural es utilizar el plugin Better Search Replace es la solución perfecta para cuando queramos sustituir un texto concreto dentro del contenido de un WordPress. Es un plugin gratuito y muy sencillo de gestionar. Para instalarlo, vas a la sección Plugins de WordPress de nuestro backoffice y seleccionas la opción Añadir Nuevo. Allí buscamos el texto «Better Search Replace» y nos debe aparecer como el primer resultado de la búsqueda. Lo instalamos y lo activamos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda opcion mas invasiva, menos recomendada por ser mas delicada seria hacer el cambio directamente en la base de datos Mysql. En el archivo wp.config.php localizable en la carpeta principal de la instalación de WordPress puedes encontrar la ubicacion de Host y credenciales de acceso a la base de datos de Wordpress, te podrias conectar utilizando MySQL Workbench. Luego que estes conectado a la base de datos debes ubicar la tabla donde este ese texto y modificarlo haciendo un UPDATE del registro.

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre uso el plugin "Real-Time Find and Replace" es muy sencillo de usar. En una de las entradas colocas la porción de HTML original y en la otra, el HTML que debe quedar finalmente. Para guardar los cambios apretas Update Settings.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]